# project layout and project utilities/libraries?

Tags: django

I am a bit confused with the project layout created since Django 1.4.
I want to add some global utilities to be used through my whole project and apps.
I tried to add a utils package at the same level of my apps but Django does not see it.

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        models.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
    utils/
        __init__.py
        shortcuts.py
```

Any advice / best practice on how to use such a global utilities package ?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: you might need to prefix it with mysite (e.g. mysite.utils)

Comment: You should look in python path to see if your new package is inside it. If you are running `manage.py runserver`, your project path is added automatically and `import utils.shortcuts` should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it to PYTHONPATH which you have to do on each machine you install your project on, you can consider adding it to the django settings (mysite/settings.py) in INSTALLED_APPS variable:

```
INSTALLED_APPS=(myapp, utils)
```

This has the effect of adding utils to the python path, so you can do things like:

```
from utils import shortcuts
```